# Unable to insert node at the front of linked list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to create a program that uses insertAtFront() to insert at the front of linked list. The first user input defines the number of nodes, followed by elements for each node (age and name). I think I am messing up the insertAtFront() method in the second class, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the headNode into insertAtFront, but it is never used.
I believe it should be

```java
public void insertAtFront(PeopleNode headNode, PeopleNode currNode) {
    currNode.nextNodeRef = headNode.nextNodeRef;    
    headNode.nextNodeRef = currNode;
}
```

Here is a visual of what is happening.  It starts like this:

`head -> person1 -> person2 -> person3 ...`

First we make the new node point to the node that head is already pointing to:

```
head -> person1 -> person2 -> person3 ...
          ^
       currNode
```

Then we make the head point to the current node:

`head -> currNode -> person1 -> person2 -> person3 ...`

Comment: Thanks! Also wanted to ask, if i want to insert at end, what do I do? As in how do I set it for that?

Comment: You would first have to find the end of the linked list, just by using `person = person.nextNodeRef` in a loop until 'nextNodeRef` is null.  Then you set nextNodeRef` to the new node you want to append at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop as below

```
for(i = 0; i < input; i++ ) {
    people = scnr.next();
    numberOfpeople=scnr.nextInt();
    currNode = new PeopleNode(people, numberOfpeople);
    lastNode.insertAtFront(headNode, currNode);
    lastNode = currNode;
}
```